# PHP script to send contact form to inbox

Tags: php, html

I have created a contact form and I would like for the details be sent to my inbox once the submit button is clicked. Clicking the submit button opens up a new mail page (see getfreepack.org). I have been advised I need a PHP script. I copied one off the web but no too sure how to use it to my advantage. I would appreciate your help.

```
$Name= $_REQUEST["Name"]; 
$Email = $_REQUEST["Email"]; 
$Phone = $_REQUEST["Phone"]; 
$JobTitle = $_REQUEST["Jobtitle"]; 
$KeySkills = $_REQUEST["Keyskills"]; 
$Attachment = $_REQUEST["Attachment"]; 

$to = "my email address@mail.com"; 
$subject = "Contact Form"; 

$message = "Name: " . $Name $message .= "\Email: " . $Email: $message .= "\n Phone: " . $ Phone; 
$message .= "\nSubject: " . $Subject; $message .= "\nCover Letter: " . $CoverLetter; 
$message .= "\n Attachment: " . $Attachment; $message .= "\nIP Adress: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$message .= "\nBrowser: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
$message .= "\n\nMessage: " . $theMessage; 

$headers = "From: $theEmail";
$headers .= "\nReply-To: $theEmail"; 

$sentOk = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 
echo "sentOk=" . $sentOk;
```

Comment: You can't have PHP variables with a space in it like `$Key Skills`. It should be `$KeySkills`

Comment: Please don't repost questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448517/php-script-in-html-coding

Answer (score 1):

A very basic one would be :

```
<?php
 $to = "someone@example.com";
 $subject = "Test mail";
 $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
 $from = "someonelse@example.com";
 $headers = "From:" . $from;
 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

If you want to go one step more check out the manual : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Cheers

Comment: he said that because w3schools contains a lot of not up to date information and can cause problems to someone learning, they are just interested to be the first to appear in a google search.

Comment: removed...;)... jus saw the w3fools..:)

Comment: Thank you Roy. 
Assuming I use the above code, will all the information on my Contact form(getfreepack.org) i.e Name= 
Email= 
Phone= 
Job title= 
Key Skills= 
Attachment=

be captured and sent to me??

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the php to get a form to send to your  email address  make the form tag like this:

> > > >>action="mailto:youremailaddress@whatever.com">
> > >       Input 
> > >       Input
> > >
> > > > 